# Add mobile number field in my moodle site

Tags: mobile, sms, field, moodle, user-accounts

How can I add a field (specifically mobile number field) in my moodle site such that every new user is asked to enter his/her mobile number. In short, the mobile number field is required.

I have to accomplish this so that i can send messages to my moodle site users via their inputted mobile number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom profile field :

Go to site admin -> users -> accounts -> user profile fields

Then create new field -> text input

Choose a shortname etc.

Then select yes for "required" and "display on sign up page"

The data will be available in

```
SELECT d.userid, d.data AS mobilephone
FROM {user_info_data} d
JOIN {user_info_field} f ON f.id = d.fieldid AND f.shortname = 'mobilenumber'
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the problem comes with the text inputs field is that strong validation can not be given. The properties give you only the maximum character limit and not also the input type to be numerical only.

Solution:
A little bit of coding would give a solution with strong validation:
Go to YourMoodleDirectory/login/signup_form.php
Add codes like shown below to the place you want the field

```
    //adding demo field - contact number
            $mform->addElement('text', 'contactno', 'Contact Number', 'maxlength="14" size="20"minlength="10"');

            $mform->setType('contactno', PARAM_TEXT);

            $mform->addRule('contactno', 'Missing contact number', 'required', null, 'server');

            $mform->addRule('contactno', 'Contact number must be numeric', 'numeric', null, 'server');
//adding demo field - contact number
```

This code is been added as per my requirements, you can make the changes in the parameters or conditions as per yours.

Cheers!!